# Hawaiian Airline with stop over: which baggage rules apply?

Tags: luggage, hawaiian-airlines

We have single booking NRT->HNL->BOS in business class with a one-week stopover in Hawaii. Unfortunately we ended with one 60 lbs bag. That was fine for the leg from Japan to Honolulu but I'm not sure what rules apply to the second leg.

Two possible interpretations:

1. Heavy bags from Hawaii to North America cost extra as stated in the rules.
2. Same rules apply for the entire booking. Since it's an international flight from Japan, the heavy bag is free.

Does anyone know how to interpret the situation? The booking doesn't specifically state any limits and just refers to the general rules which seem ambiguous. It's seems odd that different legs of the same ticket would have different allowances. I also can't tell whether there is  difference between a stopover and normal layover, where the bag would be just checked through.

We can repack thing, but I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: Have you checked the fare rules? What is the fare code?

Comment: Suggest calling the airline!

Comment: @jcaron: nothing in the booking, receipt or confirmation states a fare class (just class of service). Any attempt to read the rules for that specific booking link back the boilerplate  page. I don't know how to figure the fare class and associated fare rules.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus: I tried both phone and online chat. Wait times were prohibitive. These days "calling the airline" is rarely an option any more unless you have A LOT of patience.

Comment: Try tweeting at them

Answer (score 1):

So here is what actually happened.

The check-in agent initially stated the free weight of the bag was 50lbs since its a domestic flight (albeit the longest domestic flight in the US).

I pointed out that it would be really confusing to have different weight limits for different legs of the same ticket and that they accepted it in Japan without problems. That got them indeed thinking and since the bag was reasonably close to the weight limit, they accepted the bag without extra fee.

I'm guessing here that this is corner case, that's not well defined and that the agents have leeway to deal with it.